# How does Driver Distraction Restricted state works?

Tags: fleetboard

There are different information about how the apps react / have to behave when the truck is driving. The Developer Guidelines state (Section 7) that:

> All applications not explicitly included in the Fleetboard whitelist
>   of safe driving applications will be terminated by us at a vehicle
>   speed >2km/h.

while the Developer Documentation tells that a lock screen is shown.

What's true? Will the app be terminated (including all foreground and background services?) or is just the UI blocked?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the documentation seems to be outdated.
The app is simply put into the background. The app is not terminated, thus services are still active.